# WebRequest multiple write and read

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

After I create connection, I need to send IDs and then store response, then send again and again (usually ~60-100 IDs). Currently I did it this way:

```
public void EThread()
{
    HttpWebRequest HWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_AjaxURL);
    HWRequest.Method = "POST";
    HWRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

    string StrID;

    while(!_RequiredIDs.IsEmpty)
       if (_RequiredIDs.TryDequeue(out StrID))
           Extract(StrID, ref HWRequest);
}

public void Extract(string ID, ref HttpWebRequest HWRequest)
{
    string data = "strID=" + ID;
    byte[] Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    using (Stream SWriter = HWRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        SWriter.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
        SWriter.Close();
    }

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)HWRequest.GetResponse();

    using (Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
       _RespnseCollection.Enqueue(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

However, I got this error: `System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`. If I put HttpWebRequest inside `Extract` method it works, but that works long. This was checked on 1 thread. What is wrong with the code or the server does not support this.

Comment: what do you mean by `If I put HttpWebRequest inside Extract method it works`. Do you mean that you `recreate` a new HttpWebRequest  object every time you call the method? In your current code, your request stream is closed after first use, it would cause errors for subsequent calls

Comment: Yes, `recreate` every time, but I do not want to do it. I also remove `SWriter.Close()`. Same error. Presented approach I used with `WebClient` - everything is good, but for this purpose `WebClient` is not enough.

Comment: Can you send all IDs in one request?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the server I am sending requests to is not mine.

Comment: then i guess you must recreate your http requests. You cannot just reuse the already disposed one. To avoid blocking the thread and may improve your code a bit, you could consider asyn http requests

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am planning to use multiple single-use download threads.

Comment: The best solution is sending all IDs in one request, but we cannot do this due to external service limitation. With your current situation, i think there is no better solution than using async http requests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are re-using the HWRequest. But an `HttpWebRequest` is a single use item. In other words you can fire off the request only once.

So if thr `_RequiredIDs` contains more than one item, the first item will work properly, but change the state of the `HwRequest` to completed (ie it now contains a response) and the `HaveResponse` property will be set to true.

If you then again execute `GetRequestStream()`or `GetResponse()` it determines that, having already received a response, it does not make sense to set up the request again.

So you could modify your code as follows:

```
public void EThread()
{

    string StrID;

    while(!_RequiredIDs.IsEmpty)
       if (_RequiredIDs.TryDequeue(out StrID))
       {
           HttpWebRequest HWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_AjaxURL);
           HWRequest.Method = "POST";
           HWRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
           Extract(StrID, ref HWRequest);
       }
}
```

BUT, I suppose this is really functionally equivalent to declaring the `HttpRequest` and initializing inside the `Extract` method.

SUGGESTIION:
Try calling `HWRequest.Reset()`:

```
public void EThread()
{
    HttpWebRequest HWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_AjaxURL);
    HWRequest.Method = "POST";
    HWRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

    string StrID;

    while(!_RequiredIDs.IsEmpty)
       if (_RequiredIDs.TryDequeue(out StrID))
       {
           Extract(StrID, ref HWRequest);
           HWRequest.Reset();
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the same. The server has somewhat long time to establish connection, therefore I want to re-use connection if possible, otherwise, I will just find optimum amount of downloading threads.

Comment: But, you cannot re-use the connection with `HttpWebRequest`that's the core problem you are facing here.

Comment: Any alternative? When I used `WebClient` it works well and I think speed-up downloading, however I cannot use `WebClient` here.

Comment: I do not have `Reset()` method in HttpWebRequest. Do I miss something?